# How to write a string with space by dataBinding

Tags: android

I want to make the app show me the string like "24 girls";
but when I use dataBinding , the space in string can't be shown,the string change like "24girls".

This is my code:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. 
Please avoid pasting screenshot of the code, instead put the actual text and use `code-markup`.

Comment: thanks for everyone answer my question,thank you~

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may make this in layout:

```
android:text="@{setScore.score + ' ' + @string/score_string}"
```

But as for me better variant is create a special getter in viewmodel which will return string.

*For example:*

```
String getScoreFormatted() {
    return String.format(getString(R.string.score_string), score);
}
```

*And use it in your layout:*

```
android:text="@{setScore.scoreFormatted}"
```

Why is better? Because you may code any logic by `java` or `kotlin` in you method and your layout will be cleaner.

Answer (score 31):

I would suggest you to use [plurals](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html?hl=en#resources) for this.
In your `strings.xml` add this:

```
<plurals name="scores">
    <item quantity="one">%d Girl</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d Girls</item>
</plurals>
```

and in your layout file

```
android:text="@{@plurals/scores(setScore.score, setScore.score)}"
```

The first `setScore.score` is used to decide which string should be used from the `plurals`.
And the second `setScore.score` is for argument `%d` we mentioned in `plurals`.

Answer (score 5):

Create a string resource:

```
<string name="score_string">%1d girls</string>
```

and then use it like this:

```
android:text="@{String.format(@string/score_string, setScore.score)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

just give whitespace `+' '+` in between score and score string

Comment: And how to add empty space?